# Unable to implement SwingWorker in FTP

Tags: java, tcp, ftp, swingworker

I am trying to create FTP using TCP/IP in Java. Everything works fine in IDE, but then I decided to make it an IDE independent application by introducing GUI. In order to update GUI I implemented SwingWorker. Here is the code for my Client.java where the problem arises. Transfer gets successful but Stream is not flushed and the connection is not closed due to which the file gets corrupted. Also, GUI doesn't get updated.

**Receive Method**

```
 public void receive()throws Exception
{
    String ipadd = ipaddress.getText();
    String port1 = socketname.getText();
    String filepath = directory.getText();
    String filepath1 = filepath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
    String filename1 = name.getText();
    String finalpath = filepath1+"/"+filename1;

    int port = Integer.parseInt(port1);
    Socket s = new Socket(ipadd,port);
        byte[] contents = new byte[10000];


        File file = new File(finalpath);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        long fileLength = is.readLong();
             while((bytesRead = is.read(contents))!=1) {
        SwingWorker<Void,Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Integer>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    totalbytesread+= bytesRead;
                    bos.write(contents, 0 ,bytesRead);
                    publish(totalbytesread);
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                    int value = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                    System.out.println(value);
                    progress.setText("Received "+(value/1000000)+" MB out 

                   of "+(fileLength/1000000)+" MB.......("+

                   (value*100)/fileLength+"%)");
                    super.process(chunks); 
                } 
                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    progress.setText("File Received!!");
                    super.done(); 
            }

            };worker.execute();   
             }                
            bos.flush();
            s.close();

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Successfully Received!!");
}
```

Please help..